# I'm yearning in grey

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, wordplay

> I have made films on wood.
>   I have stopped by a park.
>   Going outside late makes me happy.
>   I'm yearning in grey.

What is my name?

Comment: Thanks for the [inspiration](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/85125/5373) :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Noice! This one was in turn inspired by [Riddle Me This!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/riddle-me-this)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have made films on wood.

> **[Ed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_Wood)** Wood was an American filmmaker.

I have stopped by a park.

> Park**ed** means stopped.

Going outside late makes me happy.

> **E**late**d** means happy.

I'm yearning in grey.

> Gre**ed**y as in having strong desires/hungering.

Comment: Yup, all correct!