# I wish, I yearn, for an answer to this riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

In a creature is my natural home.
Have me in your meal and you'll become me.
(With me, this line would be adjacent.)
Experts take more time with me.
In winter wear, I might be half a mile.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I really hope the answer is

> long

In a creature is my natural home.

> be**long**ing - meaning your natural home, the creature is a being.

Have me in your meal and you'll become me.

> e**long**ating - meaning becoming long, and eating as in your meal.

(With me, this line would be adjacent.)

> a**long**side - meaning adjacent, the remark is an aside.

Experts take more time with me.

> pro**long**/s - take more time, the experts are pro/s.

In winter wear, I might be half a mile.

> Fur**long**s - furs are winter wear, four furlongs is half a mile.

Title: I wish, I yearn, for an answer to this riddle

> long - to wish or yearn for something (such a  puzzle from jafe or Rand).

Comment: Correct answer! But there's a slightly better word to use for line 2, and a much better word to use for line 4. How about the title?

Comment: Fully correct. Your green tick will be along at some point.

Comment: Thanks @Randal'Thor - it's really amazing how swiftly you created this - jafe's [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85123/im-yearning-in-grey) was only up for 27 mins! (I especially liked the line in brackets.)

Comment: The bit about "yearning" in jafe's riddle made me think of that particular synonym, and I went looking for words containing it. Soon enough it was clear both that I was barking up the wrong tree for jafe's puzzle and that I had enough words to make a nice new puzzle :-)